# Java grid layout - 2 columns

Tags: java, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a basic GUI for booking classes in a gym. I'm not very familiar with the grid layout and struggling with creating a 2 column grid.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[Gym layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGMW.jpg)

And here's my grid code so far:

```
private void createPanel() {
    
    setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
    
    //Panel 1: member ID field
    panel1.add(memberIDLabel);
    panel1.add(memberIDField);

    panel1.add(courseNameLabel);
    panel1.add(courseNameField);
    
    panel1.add(bookButton);
    
    //Panel 4: 'view courses' and 'view members' buttons
    panel4.add(coursesButton);
    panel4.add(bookingsButton);
    
    //Attaches panels to frame
    this.add(panel1);
    this.add(panel2);
    this.add(panel3);
    this.add(panel4);
}
```

Comment: Help with what? What doesn't this do that you want it to do? Don't make us guess your question.

Comment: A 2 column `GridLayout` obviously has 2 in the second parameter of the `GridLayout` constructor?

Comment: And you should probably use `GridBagLayout` for this task. Cells in `GridLayout` are forced to have same size.